# Cron process sends email, where are these sent emails?

Tags: 14.04, email, cron

Ubuntu 14.04

I have an email process that sends an email via cron, using sendemail (which I believe is a Perl program that doesn't need an MTA). Where are these sent-emails stored? If they are stored at all?

NOTE: Since I installed sendemail, it looks like all other email packages, postfix, mail, sendmail, were uninstalled automatically.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking where the mail gets sent to (as in to root@host.tld, or the users mail when the crontab was not for root), or if the cronjob keeps a mail folder with things like 'sent mail', 'inbox', 'spam' etc etc? In the last case the answer is Nope. It just sends the mail and does not keep any logs.

Comment: If I send an email using alpine, a copy of the outgoing email is stored in a folder called "sent-email". My question is, does "sendemail" the script, save sent emails somewhere.

Comment: No, it does not. It only sends them. It does not archive them or keep local copies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script does not save its sent email, it just sends out the mail - that's all.